# Swiftui widget ios 14 problems with image downloaded from the internet

Tags: swift, image, swiftui, widget, widgetkit

[image: ui]

I have to put a background image from the internet in a widget, but it gives me the following problem.

You can tell me where I'm wrong?

Note.swift(model)

```
import Foundation

struct Note: Identifiable, Codable {
    let title: String
    let message: String

    var id = UUID()
}
```

SmallWidget.swift

```
import SwiftUI

struct SmallWidget: View {
    var entry: Note
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(alignment: .center){
            Text(entry.title)
                .font(.title)
                .bold()
                .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
                .foregroundColor(.white)
                .shadow(
                    color: Color.black,
                    radius: 1.0,
                    x: CGFloat(4),
                    y: CGFloat(4))
            Text(entry.message)
                .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
                .shadow(
                    color: Color.black,
                    radius: 1.0,
                    x: CGFloat(4),
                    y: CGFloat(4))

        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        .background(NetworkImage(url: URL(string: "https://a.wattpad.com/useravatar/climaxmite.256.718018.jpg")))
    }
}

struct SmallWidget_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        let note = Note(title: "Title", message: "Mex")
        
        Group {
            SmallWidget(entry: note)
            SmallWidget(entry: note)
                .preferredColorScheme(.dark)
        }
    }
}
```

note.swift

```
import WidgetKit
import SwiftUI

struct Provider: TimelineProvider {
    func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
        SimpleEntry(note: Note(title: "Title", message: "placeholder"))
    }

    func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
        let entry = SimpleEntry(note: Note(title: "Title", message: "getSnapshot"))
        completion(entry)
    }

    func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
        var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []

        // Generate a timeline consisting of five entries an hour apart, starting from the current date.
        let currentDate = Date()
        for hourOffset in 0 ..< 5 {
            let entryDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: hourOffset, to: currentDate)!
            let entry = SimpleEntry(note: Note(title: "Title", message: "getTimeline"))
            entries.append(entry)
        }

        let timeline = Timeline(entries: entries, policy: .atEnd)
        completion(timeline)
    }
}

struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    public let note: Note
    public let date: Date = Date()
}

struct noteEntryView : View {
    /*var entry: Provider.Entry

    var body: some View {
        Text(entry.date, style: .time)
    }*/
    
    var entry: Provider.Entry
    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) private var widgetFamily
    
    var body: some View {
        switch widgetFamily {
        case .systemSmall:
            SmallWidget(entry: entry.note)
        default:
            SmallWidget(entry: entry.note)
        }
    }
}

@main
struct note: Widget {
    let kind: String = "note"

    var body: some WidgetConfiguration {
        StaticConfiguration(kind: kind, provider: Provider()) { entry in
            noteEntryView(entry: entry)
        }
        .configurationDisplayName("My Widget")
        .description("This is an example widget.")
        .supportedFamilies([.systemSmall, .systemMedium])
    }
}

struct note_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        noteEntryView(entry: SimpleEntry(note: Note(title: "Title", message: "Mex")))
            .previewContext(WidgetPreviewContext(family: .systemSmall))
    }
}
```

NetworkImage.swift

```
import Foundation
import Combine
import SwiftUI

extension NetworkImage {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        @Published var imageData: Data?
        @Published var isLoading = false

        private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

        func loadImage(from url: URL?) {
            isLoading = true
            guard let url = url else {
                isLoading = false
                return
            }
            URLSession.shared.dataTaskPublisher(for: url)
                .map { $0.data }
                .replaceError(with: nil)
                .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
                .sink { [weak self] in
                    self?.imageData = $0
                    self?.isLoading = false
                }
                .store(in: &cancellables)
        }
    }
}

// Download image from URL
struct NetworkImage: View {
    @StateObject private var viewModel = ViewModel()

    let url: URL?

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            if let data = viewModel.imageData, let uiImage = UIImage(data: data) {
                Image(uiImage: uiImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
            } else if viewModel.isLoading {
                ProgressView()
            } else {
                Image(systemName: "photo")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .redacted(reason: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.placeholder/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            viewModel.loadImage(from: url)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It’s probably your progressview. You can’t have anything animating in a widget.

Comment: @Andrew: I don't think you take this project from which I was inspired, use the same thing: https://github.com/Arjun-dureja/SubWidget/blob/main/SubscriberWidget/View/NetworkImage.swift

Comment: In that case it seems to work, but NetworkImage is giving problems this way.

Comment: The no entry ⛔️ sign usually means that you have added something that is disallowed in a widget. The most obvious thing is the progressview as that will animate and widgets are static. Other offenders are things like scrollviews.

Comment: The no sign is for the `ProgressView` but the whole concept will not work in Widgets. Views here are static - you can't use a `@StateObject` or nothing similar. The only way to refresh a view is by recreating a timeline. What you can do is to create a network request *outside* the view. See [How to refresh Widget data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63976424/8697793).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no async image loader is going to work in a widget since widgets are static. They're declarative, but not dynamic. They're not allowed to change over time.

You can download the image in `getSnapshot()` and `getTimeline()` before calling the completion handler, then pass the image along with data in the entry.

Here's some pseudo code:

```
struct SimpleEntry: TimelineEntry {
    public let note: Note
    public let date: Date = Date()
}

func placeholder(in context: Context) -> SimpleEntry {
    // Some placeholder note + image
    SimpleEntry(note: note, date: Date())
}

func getSnapshot(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (SimpleEntry) -> ()) {
  // fetch note and image
  ...

  note.image = image

  let entry = SimpleEntry(note: note, date: Date())
  completion(entry)
}

func getTimeline(in context: Context, completion: @escaping (Timeline<Entry>) -> ()) {
  var entries: [SimpleEntry] = []
  
  // fetch note and image
  ...

  note.image = image

  let entry = SimpleEntry(note: note, date: Date())
  entries.append(entry)

  let timeline = ...
  completion(timeline)
}

struct noteEntryView : View {
    var entry: Provider.Entry

    @Environment(\.widgetFamily) private var widgetFamily
    
    @ViewBuilder
    var body: some View {
        switch widgetFamily {
        case .systemSmall:
            SmallWidget(note: entry.note)
        default:
            SmallWidget(note: entry.note)
        }
    }
}

struct SmallWidget: View {
    let note: Note

    var body: some View {
      Image(uiImage: note.image)
      ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you guide me how to download image? I tried with `Data(contentsOf: url)`  without success of showing on UIImage

Comment: @Neo.Mxn0, I used `SDWebImagePrefetcher.shared.prefetchURLs()` inside `getTimeline()` then referred to the cache in the SwiftUI using `SDImageCache.shared.imageFromCache()` .

Comment: I've just got success with `Data(contentsOf: url)` :D